# How does Ansibles Serial keyword handle execution on hosts?

Tags: ansible

I tried to search through the Ansible documentation, and while it was clear if you used "100%" at the end of the Serial (IE 10%, 20$, 100%), or if I used a number greater than my total number of expected hosts (IE 1, 5, 10)  it wasn't clear in the following scenario:

I have a hosts file that contains 10 servers, and my playbook which is serial at 25%.
I expect this to run 4 times, and in total executing the play across all 10 servers, but how does it look during an execution?

Will it round up, or down?
Will it run the first execution against 2 servers and then the next one against 3?
If I say Serial "25%", would it ever miss one of the hosts due to the total number of hosts not being divisible by 4?

```
- hosts: all
  serial: "25%"
```

Comment: The best in those kind of case is to test it. Declare then hosts in a dummy inventory, make them `ansible_connection: local` and run a play with just a dummy debug task.

Comment: The result on the case you are raising: it rounds down, so execute two hosts per two hosts, and because there are remaining hosts at the end of the four segments, it runs a fifth time. And off, course, no, it won't skip an hosts for that, the hosts in plays is a list that Ansible is going to exhaust by running on hosts then removing them from the list until there is nothing left to execute